# Logical check on rows with column index varying

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am stuck in developing a code in R for this particular task with a big dataset

sample data frame looks like :

```
   mon  abb Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov
    5   May 2   4   2   5   0   0   7   0
    5   May 6   5   1   1   3   0   6   4
    5   May 3   1   0   1   1   2   8   8
    7   Jul 5   4   1   0   0   0   9   1
    7   Jul 3   3   4   3   4   4   9   9
    7   Jul 4   2   3   3   1   2   7   4
    7   Jul 4   1   4   2   3   5   4   3
    6   Jun 4   0   4   3   3   6   5   5
    7   Jul 4   4   5   3   4   8   8   8
    5   May 4   -1  6   4   4   9   5   4
    7   Jul 4   -2  4   4   2   6   6   9
```

for each row from the month in column `abb` matching with column name month the number in the corresponding cell will be compared with succeding numbers and column `count` is created with number of times it was less than numbers in the other cells. hope its clear

```
Output would look like
mon abb Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Count
5   May 2   4   2   5   0   0   7   0   2
5   May 6   5   1   1   3   0   6   4   1
5   May 3   1   0   1   1   2   8   8   3
7   Jul 5   4   1   0   0   0   9   1   2
7   Jul 3   3   4   3   4   4   9   9   4
7   Jul 4   2   3   3   1   2   7   4   2
7   Jul 4   1   4   2   3   5   4   3   4
6   Jun 4   0   4   3   3   6   5   5   3
7   Jul 4   4   5   3   4   8   8   8   4
5   May 4   -1  6   4   4   9   5   4   6
7   Jul 4   -2  4   4   2   6   6   9   3
```

I  created column index

conshead$b=(match(conshead[,conshead$monthabb],colnames(conshead[,24:31]))+23)

not able to proceed further. Please share a better logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`.  Create a sequence column with `rownames_to_column`, `gather` the dataset to 'long' format, after grouping by the sequence ('rn'), `slice` the rows from where the 'abb' is equal to 'key', `summarise` by taking the `sum` of the logical expression (`val[-1] > first(val)`) i.e. counting how many values are greater than the first element where the match occured and bind it as a column in the original dataset ('df1')

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
     gather(key, val, Apr:Nov) %>%
     group_by(rn) %>% 
     slice((which(abb == key) ): n()) %>% 
     summarise(Count = sum(val[-1] > first(val))) %>% 
     arrange(as.integer(rn)) %>% 
     pull(Count) %>% 
     bind_cols(df1, Count = .)
#   mon abb Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Count
#1    5 May   2   4   2   5   0   0   7   0     2
#2    5 May   6   5   1   1   3   0   6   4     1
#3    5 May   3   1   0   1   1   2   8   8     3
#4    7 Jul   5   4   1   0   0   0   9   1     2
#5    7 Jul   3   3   4   3   4   4   9   9     4
#6    7 Jul   4   2   3   3   1   2   7   4     2
#7    7 Jul   4   1   4   2   3   5   4   3     4
#8    6 Jun   4   0   4   3   3   6   5   5     3
#9    7 Jul   4   4   5   3   4   8   8   8     4
#10   5 May   4  -1   6   4   4   9   5   4     6
#11   7 Jul   4  -2   4   4   2   6   6   9     3
```

---

A `base R` would be use row/column indexing to extract the elements and then create a logical matrix to get the `rowSums`

```
#column index position where the match occurs with 'abb' column and column names
i1 <- match(df1$abb, names(df1)[-(1:2)])
#replace elements in each row before the match to NA
m1 <- replace(df1[-(1:2)], cbind(rep(seq_along(i1), i1-1), sequence(i1-1)), NA)
#extract the elements where the match occured and compare it with 'm1'
df1$Count <- rowSums(m1 > df1[-(1:2)][cbind(1:nrow(df1), i1)], na.rm = TRUE)
df1$Count
#[1] 2 1 3 2 4 2 4 3 4 6 3
```

Comment: @AlbertRajan  Do you have the `dplyr`, tidyr` packages loaded

Comment: You can just do `df1 <- rownames_to_column(df1, 'rn') %>% 
     gather(key, val, Apr:Nov) %>%
     group_by(rn) %>% 
     slice((which(abb == key) ): n()) %>% 
     summarise(Count = sum(val[-1] > first(val))) %>% 
     arrange(as.integer(rn)) %>% 
     pull(Count) %>% 
     bind_cols(df1, Count = .)`